# FileOutputStream not closing properly?

Tags: java, sockets, file-handling

I have a socket program that can share files and class objects. But when I share files, the server socket sends files correctly without any errors. The client-side also gets the target file sent from the server and stored in the local folder correctly (also I can open it). But after receiving a file, the `FileOutputStream` is not closing. To check that, I put a print command at the end of the process. I'm using `Lombok` to perform close operations. The file that is written is **always lower than** `21MB` in size and the file type is `.pdf`(because the `server` manages it). This is my code block.

```java
Path dir = Paths.get("Temp");
if (Files.notExists(dir)) {
   Files.createDirectory(dir);
}
Path file = Files.createTempFile(dir, null, ".pdf");

InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

@Cleanup
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.toFile());

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
   fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

System.out.println("ok2");
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.30</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also tried this with `try-with-resources` but no good.

Comment: Put in the example using try-with-resources. Also what does "print command at the end of the process" mean?

Comment: You need something like `try (InputStream in = socket.getInputStream()) {long copied = Files.copy(in, file);}`

Comment: @DuncG lombok does that, and, OP themselves said 'it doesn't help'.

Comment: @g00se that would do the same thing. In a cleaner way and it's a nice style suggestion, but it wouldn't do anything to solve whatever OP is running into.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Although "lombok does that" is correct, apparently that isn't working. Putting in the try-with-resources example and the "print command" might help explain what is happening.

Comment: @DuncG Please take a look at [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/q6XrMGiA). By "print command at the end of the process" I mean, when I use `Lombok`, it's easy to recognize that the thread is continuously running by adding a print statement after the code block execution as the provided code.

Comment: @g00se I also tried it, but the problem exists :(

Comment: @rzwitserloot Yes, as you mentioned, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is never closing the connection. Therefore, the `read()` call on the `inputStream` eventually 'blocks' (it just sits there, waiting for more data; data that will presumably never come). You haven't exited the block so the `FileOutputStream` is never closed. You can check this if you want by adding some sysout statements or using a debugger to doublecheck this is the reason (there are some exceedingly esoteric alternative explanations, you might want to double check this).

It doesn't matter if you're asking lombok to close that or `try-with` - neither one would close here, as the code is still in the block.

The solution is generally one of protocol. You haven't explained what this server is. Many options:

- As part of the protocol, you know how many bytes there are, and you're supposed to track whether you're done or not. Once you have read as many bytes as will come, don't call `read()` again as that would block. Your `while` condition must not go `> 0`, instead decrement a `bytesLeft` counter and the while loop should loop until it hits 0.
- You wrote the server, the protocol states the connection is closed when the file is done, so there's *this* code you pasted isn't the problem, it's the server code.
- Same but someone else wrote the server, still, bugs in the server.

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved. My server does not close the OutputStream after flushing the data. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: If you want the connection to remain open, you can do that, but you'll have to design a protocol of sorts then. One option is that you _first_ send 4 bytes comprising the file size (in network order, i.e '1234' is sent as 0x00, 0x00, 0x04 0xD2), then send that many bytes. Now your client code knows when to 'stop reading'. Or, you send the file then send some unique sequence that isn't in it (`---- STOP ----` in bytes or some such) but that's much harder to put together client-side.